# How do I automatically fill the subject in the contact forms?

Tags: entities, forms, 9

I created 2 types of contact form. I disabled *Subject* in *Manage form*. I want the fake *Subject* field not to be displayed in the contact form, and I want it to be filled in automatically.

How do I automatically fill the subject in the contact forms?

There is nothing in the contact form settings to enter static text in the subject field.

Answer (score 1):

If working with Drupal contact forms (and not Webform), it would be something like:

```
  // Replace HOOK with 'yourThemeName' or 'yourModuleName' depending on where you put this code
  function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) { 
    if($form_id == "your_contact_form_id") {
      $form["subject"]["widget"][0]["value"]["#default_value"] = "Hi, how are you?";
      $form["subject"]["widget"][0]["value"]["#type"] = "hidden"; // Hide field from display 
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Set default value for the form either in settings or you can do it via hook_form_alter(). Then set the filed as disabled.

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer, but this would be a good answer if you explained further. For example, explain how to "Set default value for the form in settings" and show some hook_form_alter() code.